# how to get value?

Tags: jquery

How to get current selected value of a dropdown which is inside div?
divid is divcontent 
and dropdownid is country

code follows

```
<form id="frm1">
```

both dropdowns are ajax-generated based on some conditions.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to get the value of any input type element, include `<select>` elements.  Since IDs are unique you can just do this:

```
var value = $("#country").val();
```

Comment: Nick, how I put the additional selctor divid/formid to it, as I have two forms with same country dropdowns?

Comment: @soorajthomas - You shouldn't have the same ID, in that case strip it off, use a `name` (I'm assuming it already has), like this:    `$("#formIDHere select[name=country]").val()`, or a class if needed: `$("#formIDHere select.country").val()`

Comment: thanks a lot nick, I have two forms in same page, so Should i can have same id in them?

Comment: @soorajthomas -nope, IDs should *always* be unique in the entire page, give each form it's own unique ID, and plug that into the selector in my last comment :)

Comment: ok thanks for the tip...but still I am not getting dropdown value...the dropdwon is populated by ajax, yes its an innerhtml content in that form...pls help

Comment: @soorajthomas - do you have an example page? you've given us almost nothing to go on :)

Answer (score 0):

And with the same technique, you are able to select a value:

```
<select>
  <option value="germany">Germany</option>
  <option value="france">France</option>
</select>

$("#country").val("germany");
```

Comment: hi In my page two forms are there with the same dropdowns, so I need to differentiate/select with respect to forms, how I do the that selction?

Answer (score 0):

When you use jQuery noconflict mode then just use like so:

```
<form id='myForm1'>
<input name='username' id='username' value='WhatEver'>
<select name='YesNo' id='YesNo'>
    <option value='0'>No</option>
    <option value='1'>Yes</option>
</select>
</form>

var uname = jQuery("#username").val();
var confirm = jQuery("#YesNo").val();

console.log(uname);
```

returns: WhatEver

```
console.log(confirm);
```

returns: 1 (if Yes was selected)

But if you want get all form items at same time then use it like so:

```
var formData = jQuery("#myForm1").serialize();
console.log(formData);
```

returns: username=WhatEver&YesNo=1